# Is there any way to email out files from a folder to individual recipients?

Tags: r, email, smtp

I have made excel files and placed them in a folder on my desktop, I would like to be able to email each excel file to a corresponding recipient (I also have made a table of the excel file name and the email recipient of it). Does anyone know of a way to do this? I've been trying to use the 'blastula' package and have had no luck so far.

```
rm(list=ls())

df <- data.frame(
  file_name = c("AARCHER", "AJOHNSON", "JGOODALL"),
  email = c("email", "email", "email")
)

library(blastula)

# Set the path to the folder containing the Excel files
folder_path <- 'folder/path'

# Create SMTP credentials
create_smtp_creds_file(
  file,
  user = "email",
  provider = NULL,
  host = "blank for post",
  port = 25,
  use_ssl = TRUE
)

# Iterate over each row in the data frame and send emails
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  file_name <- paste0(df$file_name[i], ".xlsx")
  email <- df$email[i]
  
  file_path <- file.path(folder_path, file_name)
  
  if (file.exists(file_path)) {
    # Create an email
    email_obj <- compose_email(
      body = "Please find attached the Excel file.",
      title = "Excel file attachment",
      template = blastula_template
    )
    
    # Add the Excel file attachment
    email_obj <- add_attachment(email_obj, file_path)
    
    # Set the recipient and subject, and send the email
    smtp_send(
      email_obj,
      to = email,
      subject = "Excel file attachment",
      credentials = creds_file("smtp_creds.txt")
    )
    
    cat("Email sent successfully to", email, "\n")
  } else {
    cat("File", file_name, "not found.\n")
  }
}
```

This is my code, ('df' is just for testing, but it is formatted just like my real data frame) it doesn't get passed the first bit with 'create_smtp_creds_file'. I'm getting this error: Error in writeLines(serialized, file) : 'con' is not a connection

**Example of MS Excel Data:**

AARCHER   aarcher@bla.com

JGOODALL  JGOODALL@bla.com

**Example of excel file names:**

AARCHER.xlsx

JGOODALL.xlsx

Comment: I use `mailR` with Gmail. Overly complicated machinery here: https://github.com/bbolker/bbmisc/blob/master/mail_generic.R

Comment: If you're going to include code samples in a question (great idea!) please post them in a text format (e.g. cut-and-pasted text in a code block) rather than as an image ...